# How to remove status indicator on bottom of Windows 11 taskbar icon

Tags: windows, icons, taskbar

In the new Windows 11 taskbar there is a line under each icon which changes color and size - large blue for focused app, small grey for open app etc.

Is there a way to disable this line entirely or at least hide the grey bar which is extremely annoying and unnecessary until you have a lot of windows open since the open apps have a wider area with a text description?

Comment: Does option "*Show accent color on start and taskbar*" fit your wish? Command: `reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v ColorPrevalence /d 0 /t reg_dword /f`